# In theorem style, how to make the dot font depend on the name font ?

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I have to use the `thmtools` package to style my theorems, lemmas, remarks etc.

Unfortunately, I noticed that when I give an optional name to a remark for instance this name is in normal font, but the dot after it is in bold and it stands out as not nice IMPO!

I want to keep in bold font the name remark and the dot when there is no optional name but I want the dot in normal font when there is one optional name. How do I do it?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove=6pt plus 0pt minus 2pt, spacebelow=0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt, headfont=\bfseries, bodyfont=\normalfont, postheadspace=5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt]{myremstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=myremstyle,name=Remarque,numbered=no]{rem}

\begin{document}
\begin{rem}[not quite nice effect]
\end{rem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252391/tweaking-theorem-style-last-parameter-traps

Comment: @egreg You are absolutely right to point at my own previous question ! The answer given there worked well. Unfortunately here in this document I am using the package thmtools. Is it possible to tweak it the same way or should I get rid of it ?

Comment: @egreg I had to use to this package because I needed the listoftheorem function. So if I get rid of it, I have to do the macro myself ...

Comment: Have you considered using the `ntheorem` package and using that package's `\listtheorems` command?

Comment: @mico Yes. But some incompatibilities happened with amsbook class. So I invested lots of time tweaking my lists with thmtools. I really do not want to change and learn the details again ... But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Mico But I agree with you : it is a bit unfortunate the thmtools package do not take care of this bothersome detail ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons I don't understand, the note is typeset in a group. Anyway, the workaround is not pretty, because you need to specify `headformat` in all styles you define.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% don't typeset the note in a group, so the punctuation inherits
% the font specification of the note
\patchcmd{\thmt@setheadstyle}
 {\bgroup\thmt@space}
 {\thmt@space}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\thmt@setheadstyle}
 {\egroup\fi}
 {\fi}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt plus 0pt minus 2pt,
  spacebelow=0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt,
  headfont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,
  headformat=\NAME\NOTE,
]{myremstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt plus 0pt minus 2pt,
  spacebelow=0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt,
  headfont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,
  headformat=\NAME\ \NUMBER\NOTE,
]{myfoostyle}

\declaretheorem[
  style=myremstyle,
  name=Remarque,
  numbered=no
]{rem}

\declaretheorem[
  style=myfoostyle,
  name=Foo,
]{foo}

\begin{document}

\begin{rem}[nice effect]
Some remark
\end{rem}
\begin{rem}
Some remark
\end{rem}
\begin{foo}[nice effect]
Some foo
\end{foo}
\begin{foo}
Some foo
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `headformat` with `\NAME`, `\NUMBER`, `\NOTE`, and apply `\normalfont` if there is annotation:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=6pt plus 0pt minus 2pt, 
  spacebelow=0pt plus 0pt minus 2pt, 
  headfont=\bfseries, 
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,
  headformat={\NAME~\NUMBER\NOTE\if\empty\relax\else\normalfont\fi}
]{myremstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=myremstyle,name=Remarque,numbered=no]{rem}

\begin{document}
\begin{rem}[quite nice effect]
test text.
\end{rem}
\begin{rem}
test text.
\end{rem}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: `\NOTE` is never empty; its definition is `\if=<note>=...\fi`. And, anyway, `\if\NOTE\empty` is conceptually wrong. The code works but not for the reason you are thinking to.

Comment: @egreg Hmmm. That's what I thought and it explains why my attempts with `\detokenize` failed, but then why is my code with `\empty` working? What is the conceptually good approach?

Comment: Remove `\empty` and it will work the same.

Comment: @egreg You're right. Let me think on what is going on.

Comment: @egreg I give up. I don't quite understand why my code works. I guess you do know, so would you please explain what's going on?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina +1 You answer works fine with me even if it is not conceptually satisfying as egreg pointed out (I would not have noticed it myself ...). I need some time to compare its reliability with the "not pretty" one of egreg !

Comment: @brunoh My “not pretty” refers to the need of specifying `headformat` in any style.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina After careful analysis, I have two comments : 1/ your last edit to your answer does not work anymore for me. I have to use \if\NOTE\empty to make it work, which was your initial answer ... 2/ it has some unfortunate side effects to leave a space between the name of the style and the dot in case I choose the not numbered option. The solution of egreg specifically avoid that. But thank you for your efforts !