# theorem word in italic not in bold

Tags: theorems

I want use theorem of LaTeX but I don't want the word "theorem" in bold. After I want like image in italic but not in bold. How set this?
I only want change for observation and don't want change all "teorema" "lemma" etc,

Here make something similar:

[Tweaking theorem style last parameter traps?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252391/tweaking-theorem-style-last-parameter-traps)

[image: how i want]

This is my preamble code:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corolario}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lema}
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definición}
\newtheorem{ejem}[theorem]{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{obsa}[theorem]{Observación}
\newtheorem{pro}[theorem]{Proposición}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required theorem style is predefined:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}[theorem]{Proposición}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corolario}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lem}[theorem]{Lema}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defin}[theorem]{Definición}
\newtheorem{ejem}[theorem]{Ejemplo}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{obsa}[theorem]{Observación}
\newtheorem*{nota}{Notación}

\begin{document}

\section{Prueba}

\begin{theorem}
En todo triángulo rectángulo el cuadrado de la hipotenusa es igual 
a la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos.
\end{theorem}

\begin{pro}
En todo triángulo rectángulo el cuadrado de la hipotenusa es igual 
a la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos.
\end{pro}

\begin{cor}
En todo triángulo rectángulo el cuadrado de la hipotenusa es igual 
a la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos.
\end{cor}

\begin{defin}
En todo triángulo rectángulo el cuadrado de la hipotenusa es igual 
a la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos.
\end{defin}

\begin{ejem}
En todo triángulo rectángulo el cuadrado de la hipotenusa es igual 
a la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos.
\end{ejem}

\begin{obsa}
En todo triángulo rectángulo el cuadrado de la hipotenusa es igual 
a la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos.
\end{obsa}

\begin{nota}
En todo triángulo rectángulo el cuadrado de la hipotenusa es igual 
a la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos.
\end{nota}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: now work fine. thanks so much. i dont know about different style theorem and remark

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{mythm}{3pt}{3pt}{}{}{\itshape}{:}{.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{mythm}
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{mytheorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just what i need it. thanks so much

Comment: i was looking, but it change all teorem style, only want observation